# Execute onPostExecute on cancelling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As far as I understand once an AsyncTask is called, the result is changed to null and the AsyncTask is cancelled. Is there a way to retain the result and pass it to `onPostExecute(String result)`. `developer.android.com` says not to call these functions explicitly.

The app basically scans images and if a user cancels the async task, I'd like the async task to display the images scanned so far. So the result should not be set to null.

Is this possible to accomplish? If yes, how?

```
class openCVOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    private MainActivity context = null;
    /*lots of variables here*/
    public openCVOperation(MainActivity context1) {
        context = context1;// set context from mainActivity
                                        // which
                                        // inherits Activity super class.
                                        // Needed
                                        // for accessing widgets.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMax(100);
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.setMessage("Starting up");
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Finding path to Storage...");
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        p = path.getAbsolutePath();
        p=p+"/location";
        rm(p);// this has a loop!
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        System.out.println("In onCancelled");
        super.onCancelled();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        /*post execute stuff*
    }
```

`rm(p)` has a loop, so I tried using `isCancelled()` as a condition, but that didn't work.

Comment: can u post your code? where do you cancel your asynctask?

Comment: I cancel the asynctask in the UI. I've overridden the back button, it doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add this to my `doInBackground()`

```
pd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                task.cancel(true);
            }
        });
```

Where `pd` is my progress dialog.

Also make sure you check for `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground()` or `onCancelled()` will never be invoked and the application will force close.

Answer (score 1):

In the doInBackground

```
if (isCancelled())
{
    return // image so far
}


onPostExecute(String result)
{

     // show result
}
```

Comment: The thing is it's a `String` type function. So I must return a string value. What exactly do I have to return? I have a lot of variables required in the `onPostExecute(String result)`.

Comment: How do get the scan image if you return a string?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is not invoked when the `AsyncTask` was cancelled.

Comment: Basically, the app reads images and if it finds the image of a certain color, it marks it with a boolean variable. Two arraylists.

Comment: @323go - I had another function called from `onCancelled()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Define "didn't work." I use the pattern I posted in my answer all the time, and it works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the results:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
  private final List<String> data;

  public MyTask(){
    data =  new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public synchronized List<String> getData(){
    return new ArrayList<String>(data); //--current data snapshot--
  }

  private synchronized collect(String s){
    data.add(s);
  }     

  @Override
  public Void doInBackground(Void...args){
    //---do stuff--
    collect(/*-stuff-*/);
  }
}
```

You won't lose anything even if thread is interrupted.

Answer (score -1):

If `onCancelled` is not being called, then your `rm` method is still running.
Because as you mentioned, it's running a loop.

The best way to control the process (know if it needs to be stopped) is by polling or tediously checking the status of a `volatile boolean` variable within your `rm` method.

For example, create a `static volatile boolean` variable within your AsyncTask class called `cancel`.  Set this variable to `false` in the `onPreExecute` method.

In your `rm` method, check to see if `cancel` is true before and after the heavy tasks (opening a file, reading a file, part of a download loop).

If it's true, then break out of the method with a `return` statement.
Better yet, make your `rm` method return an Integer, 0 for Good and 1 for cancelled.

And finally, right before the `doInBackground` method hits return, see if you need to call a cancel on the thread or not.

```
public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private static synchronized boolean cancel;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        cancel = false;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void ... params)
    {

        rm(p);

        if(cancel)
            asyncTask.cancel;
        else
            return null;
    }

    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        // only executed if doInBackground resulted in a cancel == true
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param)
    {
        /// only executed if doInBackground resulted in a cancel == false 
    }

    private int rm(String str)
    {
        if(cancel)
            return 1;

        //do part of task

        if(cancel)
            return 1;

        //another part of task

        if(cancel)
            return 1;

        //another part of task

        return cancel ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```